# Copy specific sub-directory and keep directory tree structure

Tags: linux, rsync

In my working directory, I have 3 directories that each has 3 sub directories named exactly the same.  Files are located in the sub directories.  I would like to copy a specific sub directory (and files) to a new location, but keep the same directory tree structure.  I have tried using rsync unsuccessfully.  Example of what I would like to accomplish is shown below.

Start With:

directory1

```
sub1 

sub2

sub3
```

dirctory2

```
 sub1

 sub2

 sub3
```

directory3

```
 sub1

 sub2

 sub3
```

Desired folder structure after the copy (and retain files in sub2):

directory1

```
 sub2
```

directory2

```
 sub2
```

directory3

```
 sub2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you've tagged `rsync` and mention having tried it, but why not plain old cp?

```
mkdir newdir
cp --parents -rp directory[123]/sub2 newdir
```

This will give you the desired result.